# How should I use mines in CoH?

Tags: company-of-heroes

Mines can be placed anywhere and cause heavy damage to any enemy moving over them. However, they are not free, and require resources and time to be set up.

Where and when should I lay down mines? The general idea should be to have them cover paths that are often crossed and places of strategic relevance (e.g. VPs), but are there any details or tricks that increase effectiveness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antivehicle mines should go on roads, in general.  Many players will micromanage their tanks to avoid roads;  however, the default AI pathfinding prefers roads for the speed bonus.  So if you put mines (especially those nice PE AT ones) on roadways, you WILL get vehicle kills.

Also, if you can get mines on the enemy's "reinforcement road" (the road by which his off-map reinforcements arrive) you can frequently get some high-value kills on enemy units just as the enemy was hoping to turn the tide of battle on you.

Antipersonnel mines should go near buildings and cover where the enemy will try to take cover;  they're also exceedingly useful for watching the 'flanks' of your machine guns;  if the enemy knows that a certain approach is covered with a gun, he will try to flank you with an infantry team.  This flanking path is predictable, and easily mined.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on the map.  Most have choke points that, during the infantry phase can slow the advancement of your opponent(s).  Often, your opponent(s) will also try to take cover in nearby buildings, mining the entryways can chop them into pieces when they seek shelter.

Once the heavy vehicles roll out, though, it becomes a question of whether its worth the resources to deploy them or not.  Often times, your resources are better spent countering tanks directly or bringing anti-infantry vehicles into play.

It also depends on your faction choice.  Mines are a better option for the Brits, because they are attuned to a more turtled style of play.  Panzer Elite, by contrast, is a highly mobile military and using too many mines can actually be a detriment as you try to maneuver around the battlefield.